# Encrypting a string using OpenSSL AES256 with a shared password and a specific salt value

Tags: c#, bash, openssl, aes

In my c# program (shown below) I'm using the following way to encrypt a string before transmitting it over the internet to another server for further processing. Now I have to make a bash script that does the exact same thing, but I've nearly never touched a linux server before, let stand using encryption in linux.

Currently I've managed to get as far as possible as this, but since it isn't getting accepted on the remote server, I guess I've probably forgotton something important.

```
encodedValue=$(echo $stringValue| openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -pass pass:$sharedSecret)
encodedValue=$( echo $encodedValue| tr -d ' ' )

# - base64 it
encodedValue=$( echo $(echo $encodedValue| base64) | tr -d ' ' )
```

As far as I already see the differences, I'm not giving the Salt to the openssl encoding, but I haven't found any way to do this using OpenSSL.

Can anybody point me in the good direction or show me what I'm doing wrong?

The original working c# code is shown below:

```
RijndaelManaged aesAlg = null;

try
{
    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(sharedSecret, Salt);

    aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
    aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);

    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
    using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
    {
        msEncrypt.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(aesAlg.IV.Length), 0, sizeof(int));
        msEncrypt.Write(aesAlg.IV, 0, aesAlg.IV.Length);

        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
            {
                swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
            }
        }
        outStr = Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try add `-S <salt>` parameter. See https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/enc.html

Comment: Hello, I already tried it but the salt that I'm using in the c# application is too large for the OpenSSL. At least that is what they error is telling me: "hex string is too long, invalid hex salt value"

Comment: The salt is actually getting accepted in the c# code but not in the openssl version... any ideas on how to get the same value to work?